# Cypress throwing cypress.io chrome-error://chromewebdata/ error when clicking a button

Tags: ajax, cypress

When clicking a button that takes me to another page, Cypress stops and just shows me a cypress.io chrome-error://chromewebdata/ error.

The code I'm using is simple:

```
  cy.get('button').contains('Go Search').trigger('click')
```

And the code I'm attempting to click is this:

```
<button name="GoSearch" value="Go Search" onclick="navToPage('user/gosearch.cfm','');return false;">Go Search</button>
```

I think it may have something to do with this being an AJAX call, but not for certain.  If it is, am I approaching this the wrong way?

Comment: Can I ask why `trigger('click')` and not `click()`, and are they equivalent?

Comment: I've actually tried both and they appear to act the same.

Comment: Ok, so that's my obvious guess eliminated. The `cfm` extension seems to relate to ColdFusion, my next guess is the link shouldn't have the extension on it.

Comment: I thought the same, but I have no way to change that though.

Comment: I've even tried removing the .cfm to see if anything different happens. but nope.

Comment: What does your code for `navToPage` look like? Can you show a screenshot of the failing test?

Answer (score 0):

cypress does not supports navigation between multiple domains

Answer (score 0):

Question is a bit old but this solution might apply for some scenarios where people receive that error message. Consider adding the following to the cypress.json file.

```
{
    "chromeWebSecurity": false,
}
```

Doing so allows:

- Display insecure content
- Navigate to any superdomain without cross-origin errors
- Access cross-origin iframes that are embedded in your application

See https://docs.cypress.io/guides/guides/web-security.html#Set-chromeWebSecurity-to-false for more information.